# Pytest collects tests but fails silently

Tags: python, testing, pytest, ros, ros2

I'm trying to run my project tests using github actions, and I've successfully set up the workflow such that the environment mimics our normal dev environment. However, when running tests, 2 out of 310 fail, and they fail silently, i.e. there are no tracebacks, no error messages, nothing. Here are the single test outputs when working correctly (dev environment) and not working (github action).

**SUCCESS**

```
-- run_test.py: extra environment variables:
 - COVERAGE_FILE=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.coverage
-- run_test.py: invoking following command in '<project_directory>/build/sim_interface':
 - <home_directory>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/rc/bin/python3.10 -u -m pytest <project_directory>/src/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py -o cache_dir=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/ament_cmake_pytest/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.cache --junit-xml=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/test_results/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py.xunit.xml --junit-prefix=sim_interface --cov=<project_directory>/src/sim_interface --cov-report=html:<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.html --cov-report=xml:<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.xml --cov-branch

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
cachedir: build/sim_interface/ament_cmake_pytest/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.cache
rootdir: <project_directory>
plugins: ament-xmllint-0.12.6, launch-testing-ros-0.19.4, ament-flake8-0.12.6, ament-pep257-0.12.6, ament-copyright-0.12.6, launch-testing-1.0.4, ament-lint-0.12.6, cov-4.1.0, dash-2.10.2, typeguard-2.13.3, colcon-core-0.12.1, rerunfailures-11.1.2, repeat-0.9.1
collected 2 items

../../src/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py ..                   [100%]

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/rc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glfw/__init__.py:916
  Warning: (65544) b'X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing'

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
- generated xml file: <project_directory>/build/sim_interface/test_results/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py.xunit.xml -

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.6-final-0 -----------
Coverage HTML written to dir <project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.html
Coverage XML written to file <project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.xml

======================== 2 passed, 1 warning in 11.86s =========================


-- run_test.py: return code 0
-- run_test.py: verify result file '<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/test_results/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py.xunit.xml'
```

**FAILURE**

```
-- run_test.py: extra environment variables:                                                                                                  
 - COVERAGE_FILE=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.coverage                                 
-- run_test.py: invoking following command in '<project_directory>/build/sim_interface':                                                  
 - <home_directory>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/rc/bin/python3.10 -u -m pytest <project_directory>/src/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.
py -o cache_dir=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/ament_cmake_pytest/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.cache --junit-xml=<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/test_results/sim_interface/tests/test_sim_interface.py.xunit.xml --junit-prefix=sim_interface --cov=<project_directory>/src/sim_interface --cov-report=html:<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.html
 --cov-report=xml:<project_directory>/build/sim_interface/pytest_cov/tests/test_sim_interface.py/coverage.xml --cov-branch                
                                                                                                                                              
============================= test session starts ==============================                                                              
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0                                                                        
cachedir: build/sim_interface/ament_cmake_pytest/tests/test_sim_interface.py/.cache                                                           
rootdir: <project_directory>                                                                                                              
plugins: ament-xmllint-0.12.6, ament-pep257-0.12.6, launch-testing-ros-0.19.4, ament-flake8-0.12.6, ament-copyright-0.12.6, ament-lint-0.12.6,
 launch-testing-1.0.4, dash-2.10.2, cov-4.1.0, colcon-core-0.12.1, typeguard-2.13.3, rerunfailures-11.1.2, repeat-0.9.1                       
collected 2 items
```

This is a ROS2/Humble project, so tests are ran using colcon test. The exact command is as follows:

```
colcon test --ctest-args --rerun-failed --output-on-failure --cov-report=term --pytest-with-coverage --pytest-args -k test1 --packages-select sim_interface
```

I've tried adding the `--debug`, `--loopuntilfail`, `-rf`, etc. options, but since the tests fail before they even ran, none of these options show anything new. The two environments have the same python packages (all version pinned), use the same python version (both installed via pyenv), and all plugins use the same versions. I'm at a loss for what to try next.

I tried to add debugging options to pytest, including `--debug`, `--loopuntilfail`, `-rf`.